# Python sys.argv and input combination with a definition NOT working

Tags: python, input, pycharm, definition, argv

I have a python script like below that I was trying to run in shell. I want to use either `argv` or `input` in order to give specific inputs called index1 and index2 (`ACCGTCG` and `TTCCAGC`) and a file name to process. I tried two ways (with sys.argv and input separately) as below but I get no output.

With sys.argv:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from Bio import SeqIO

def dual_index_positions():
    script=sys.argv[0]
    index1=sys.argv[1]
    index2=sys.argv[2]
    input_file=sys.argv[3]
    count=0 
    with open(input_file, "r") as Fastq:
        for record in SeqIO.parse(Fastq,'fastq'): 
            if index1 in record.seq and index2 in record.seq: 
                print(record.name)
                ind1_rec=record.seq.find(index1) 
                ind2_rec=record.seq.find(index2)
                rp_ind2=ind2_rec+len(index2)
                dist=(ind1_rec)-(rp_ind2)
                print('Index1 and index2 positions are '+ str(ind1_rec+1) + ' and ' + str(ind2_rec+1) + ' respectively' +
                  '; distance is: ' + str(dist))
                count+=1
    print('The total number of hits is: '+ str(count))
    


if __name__ == '__dual_index_positions__':
    dual_index_positions()
```

with taking inputs:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Bio import SeqIO 

def dual_index_positions(): 
    input_file=input('please enter your input_file: ')
    index1=str(input('please enter your index 1: '))
    index2=str(input('please enter your index 2: '))
    count=0 
    with open(input_file, "r") as Fastq:
        for record in SeqIO.parse(Fastq,'fastq'):
            if index1 in record.seq and index2 in record.seq: 
                print(record.name)
                ind1_rec=record.seq.find(index1) 
                ind2_rec=record.seq.find(index2)
                rp_ind2=ind2_rec+len(index2)
                dist=(ind1_rec)-(rp_ind2)
                print('Index1 and index2 positions are '+ str(ind1_rec+1) + ' and ' + str(ind2_rec+1) + ' respectively' +
                  '; distance is: ' + str(dist))
                count+=1
    print('The total number of hits is: '+ str(count))
    


if __name__ == '__dual_index_positions__':
    dual_index_positions()
```

Can somebody help me with this to find where is the bug? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "I get no output"?

Comment: `if __name__ == '__dual_index_positions__':` this is usually `if __name__ == '__main__':` you dont use the file name there if you are running it directly

Comment: I run the code using shell but nothing gets processed or printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
if __name__ == '__dual_index_positions__':
    dual_index_positions()
```

Use this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dual_index_positions()
```

`__name__ == '__dual_index_positions__'` the RHS of that is not the function name you have to call, that is the name of the module and by default it has the value `__main__`